# Senior picture 72 dpi vs 300 dpi

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, digital, dpi

So i took my senior pictures and it said it was at 72 dpi. My school said they needed pictures to at least 300 dpi. I researched and found out that 300 dpi is the best printing quality. I changed the dpi from 72 to 300 but i did not resample the image so the length and width of the picture remained the same. Is this something good or bad? I'm scared that I did something wrong and that my picture will be blurry in the yearbook. 
Help please!

Comment: Did the number of pixels stay the same or the number of inches?  The DPI doesn't have any meaning other than in the meta data that indicates the intended print size of the image.  See the Q/A that Philip mentioned for more details.

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate of that question, but the answer is the same - DPI for digital photos is meaningless, so your school shouldn't be specifying it as a criterion.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - well it works fine as a criterion as long as they also have an image size specified, though it does make it considerably more confusing to a non-photographer than just giving an actual pixel dimensions requirement.